# Smallest PCIe 4x box?

Tags: pc, pcie

I'm looking to build a small FFmpeg based video encoder using a BlackMagic Intensity Pro 4K capture card.  This card requires a PCIe 4x slot.  What's the smallest motherboard/case combination that will hold a 4x card?

There are lots of small barebones systems, but most have mini PCIe (1x) connectors, and all of the PCIe risers I've found are either 1x to 1x or 1x to 16x.  The 16x connector is way too large.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only Mini-ITX board I've been able to find with a PCIe x4 slot is the [Mitac PH12LI](http://www.logicsupply.com/ph12li/).  It is not, however, any smaller than any of the PCIe x16 Mini-ITX boards.

Personally, I'd recommend a [Casetronic C292](http://www.logicsupply.com/c292/) case, an [over-the-board PCIe x16 riser card](http://www.logicsupply.com/pciex16-c292/), and the PCIe x16 Mini-ITX board of your choice.  Your x4 card should work just fine in an x16 slot, and you won't need to go looking for parts that probably don't exist.

(No association with LogicSupply, they're just my go-to source for looking up all things Mini-ITX.)